# How to select only integers in a list of strings/integers?

Tags: python, list, iterator, list-comprehension

I have a list (actually an iterable) which was created using this function of python's itertools library:

```
comb = [c for i in range(len(menu)+1) for c in combinations(menu, i)]
```

To give you an idea `menu` is a list in this format [ ["name of food", grams of sugar] ]:

```
menu = [ ["cheesecake",  13], ["pudding", 24], ["bread", 13], .........]
```

So `comb` is essentially a list that contains all of the possible combinations of menu sublists. I have to iterate through comb create ALL of the possible item combinations, whose total sugar content will equal EXACTLY (NOT LESS, NOT MORE, EXACTLY) `max_sugar = 120`.

So I figured that I could iterate over each possible combination in `comb` and check with an `if` statement if the sum of the sugar of the items in this combination equals EXACTLY `max_sugar`. If that is the case I want to output the names of the menu items in this combination. Otherwise I want to continue through the other combinations in this manner:

```
for e in comb:
    for l in e:
        if sum(sugars of items in this combination) == max_sugar:  # pseudo-code
            print items in this combination  #pseudo code
```

I guess the problem I am having is to access only the sugar values of each item in `l` and check the condition and if it is `TRUE` print the names. 
I am not proficient in python list comprehensions but I have improved a lot in the past few days!

```
flag = 0
num_comb = 1
comb = [c for i in range(len(menu)+1) for c in combinations(menu, i)]

for e in comb:
    if sum(l[1] for l in e) == targetSugar:
        print "The combination number " + str(num_comb) + " is:\n" 
        print([l[0] for l in e])
        print "\n\n\n"
        num_comb += 1 
        flag = 1

if flag == 0:
    print "there are no combinations of dishes for your sugar intake... Sorry! :D "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the items `e` in `comb` is a tuple of lists, e.g.:

```
e == (['cheesecake', 13], ['bread', 13])
```

Therefore each of the items `l` in `e` is a list:

```
l == ['cheesecake', 13]
```

For this list, the string `cheesecake` is `l[0]` and the integer `13` is `l[1]`. Therefore, you probably want:

```
for e in comb:
    if sum(l[1] for l in e) == max_sugar:
        print([l[0] for l in e])
```

As `wim` has suggested, you could also use "unpacking" to split each list into sensible names as you iterate, which makes the code a little clearer:

```
for e in comb:
     if sum(sugar for name, sugar in e) == max_sugar:
         print([name for name, sugar in e])
```

For the short `menu` list you give and with `max_sugar == 26`, I get:

```
['cheesecake', 'bread']
```

Or with `max_sugar == 37`:

```
['cheesecake', 'pudding']
['pudding', 'bread']
```

Comment: Clearer to use unpacking i.e. `for name, sugar in e`

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know it's a very simple and "dumb" question but if I have an `if sum(sugar for name, sugar in e) == max_sugar:` I can place as many print statement indented one tab below the `if` statement correct? If I have one it runs perfectly but if I add more than one `print` statement indented all at 1 tab below the `if` it say that the 2nd, 3rd.. etc `unexpected indent`.. why is that? I am pretty new at python

Comment: I'm afraid I can't debug that without seeing the code you are trying to run.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I will add it to the question above.

Comment: It is a separate question, please treat it as such.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok sorry I will post it in a separate question! thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: "Unexpected indent" may mean you've accidentally mixed spaces with tabs (stick to one or the other, preferably spaces, and make sure your editor is set to use spaces-for-tabs) or done different numbers of spaces on different lines that you intended to indent the same.

Comment: You could also avoid the useless `e` variable and the double unpacking by unpacking directly from comb: `for name, sugar in comb`. And for me, it is clearer too.

Comment: @tinchou I agree that `e` is a poor variable name, but `name, sugar in comb` would only work when `i == 2` and those variable names would make sense; both `name` and `sugar` would be two-tuples

Comment: It would make sense in the current context :). It will always work if you're unpacking a two-tuple. Then the variable naming is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

As you were alluding to, you can use a list comprehension to iterate through all menu combinations, and restrict to those `meals` with exactly the sugar amount you are looking for:

```
>>> # input data
>>> menu = [ ["cheesecake",  13], ["pudding", 24], ["bread", 13] ]
>>> max_sugar = 26
>>> # construct all combinations of menu items
>>> comb = [c for i in range(1, len(menu)+1) for c in combinations(menu, i)]
>>> list(comb)
[(['cheesecake', 13],), (['pudding', 24],), (['bread', 13],), (['cheesecake', 13], ['pudding', 24]), (['cheesecake', 13], ['bread', 13]), (['pudding', 24], ['bread', 13]), (['cheesecake', 13], ['pudding', 24], ['bread', 13])]
>>> # restrict to meals with exactly max_sugar
>>> meals = [ e for e in comb if sum( sugar for _, sugar in e) == max_sugar ]
>>> meals
[(['cheesecake', 13], ['bread', 13])]
```

The only tricky part is when you're iterating through each combination, each element `e` is a list containing a name and the sugar count. Thus you can measure the amount of sugar in a combination `e` using:

```
sum( sugar for _, sugar in e) == max_sugar
```

Building off of this, if you only wanted to return the names of the foods in each meal, you could use:

```
>>> [ [name for name, sugar in m] for m in meals ]
[['cheesecake', 'bread']]
```

Comment: Actually I want to essentially check in each possible meal if the sum of the sugar of all items in that meal equal EXACTLY the `max_sugar`. I hope this makes more sense. Because I want to output all of the possible meals (could be composed of 1, 2 or 3 or ... items as long as the sum of their sugar equals EXACTLY the `max_sugar`. So after creating all the possible combinations of meals I am pretty much trying to filter out the ones that satisfy my condition and trying to output the names only of the items in each of these meals

Comment: @user3245453: the code I demo-ed finds all combinations of menu items with EXACTLY `max_sugar`. You can then output the names of each menu item for each of those `meals` using the code snippet at the end of my answer.